# 301 редирект для React

Tags: reactjs, seo, redirect

Изучаю React, следовательно назрел вопрос. Возможно ли сделать 301 редирект со страниц example.com/index.html, example.com/index.htm на example.com/ ?

Естественно этих страниц не существует и они выдают 404, но это стандартная задача от SEO специалистов, поэтому интересуюсь, как это реализовать. В обычных сайтах на PHP это делается через .htaccess, вот ищу что-то подобное на React.

Comment: Вы путаете немного понятия. 301 404 это ответ сервера. Php это то что обрабатывается на сервере. React это клиентская библиотека. Почитайте про роутинг в React

Comment: https://reactrouter.com/